# mongo shell script: await update op

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I've written a mongo shell script that updates multiple dbs and collections. But I noticed that the script exits before everything is updated. Is there a way to wait until an update op on one db is completed before moving on to the next db to update?

Here is a small example (not containing all data):

```
var mongoURL = 'localhost:27017';
var db1URL = mongoURL + '/db1';
var db2URL = mongoURL + '/db2';

var db1 = connect(db1URL);
var db2 = connect(db2URL);

db1.getCollection(col1).update(
    { "name": recName, "sources.name": oldCh}, {$set: {"sources.$.name": newCh}}
);

db2.getCollection(col2).update(
    { rec: recName, sources: oldCh}, {$set: { "sources.$": newCh}}
);
```

I need the update on `db2` to wait until the update on `db1` is completed. In other words, I don't want the script to exit until everything is updated. So that the operator executing the script, knows exactly how long it took (as we have many docs per collection per db)

PS. Using mongo 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the `db.getLastError()` or `db.getLastErrorObj()` does exactly what I'm looking for.

Was somewhat hidden in the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo

> Inside the script, call db.getLastError() explicitly to wait for the result of write operations.